# Stack Exchange query for top 50 users showing time out every time

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was checking a query for the top 50 users with most edits on `data.stackexchange.com`, but that query was getting timed out every time I tried to run that query. Here is the link for that.

[Top 50 Most Prolific Editors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors)

[image: Error]

After updating the query I am not able to see desired results. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Error]

Comment: Seems like a bug in your SQL, not in the system...

Comment: is it working on your end?

Comment: @cybermonkey updated title

Comment: @TZHX I don't think it's that; it's been starred 30 times and is almost 6 years old. I think something else is going on here, and for that reason I also think that it's a really good question to ask. Might be a bug in the system, I'll try and get one of the 'gurus' to confirm the query.

Comment: @cybermonkey it's trying to scan the posts table three times for every user on Stack Overflow. Six years ago there was a lot less data. The query probably hasn't worked for a while.

Comment: @TZHX Confirmed that it works for Meta but **not** Stack Overflow, you could be correct.

Comment: @TZHX and still this was downvoted

Comment: That's a very intense and very poorly written query. I'm not at all surprised it's timing out.

Comment: @Vivek That's nice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about programming problems belong on SO Main.

Comment: @TylerH this is not related to programming, it relates to data.stackexchange site and on that site it is all about queries

Comment: @TylerH please read the question carefully . I know you can see sql queries as answer but that doesn't mean it is a programming question.

Comment: `Why this question in Hot-meta list?` it's just wrong query execution.

Answer (score 14):

That query times out because it runs 3 queries for every user. Back in the days the users table wasn't that big so the punishment for a bad query was covered by hardware.

I re-implemented that [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476172):

```
select top 50 -- only the top 50 users
       p.lasteditoruserid as [User Link]
     , sum(case 
           when posttypeid = 1 then 1  -- Questions
           else 0
           end
       ) as questions
     , sum(case 
           when posttypeid = 2 then 1  -- Answers
           else 0
           end
       ) as answers
     , count(*) as total     -- rowcount per user
from posts p
where posttypeid in (1,2) -- only questions and answers (exclude wiki's)
and p.lasteditoruserid is not null
group by p.lasteditoruserid
order by count(*) desc
```

and this one does run to completion:

[image: users that edit a lot]

Here is the execution plan for the new query:

[image]

Comment: but it is not showing expected result

Comment: It shows this `{"running":true,"job_id":"98416500-f565-46a6-a01a-a38e3d65a3f2"}`

Comment: @VivekMishra I can't repro that, it works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: firefox windows 10

Comment: and I think your query is bit wrong as number of questions and answers are exactly same in the image you posted

Comment: Also I think there is some issue with the url of that query here it is `http://data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/476172/603177`. What I suspect there should not be 2 six digits number at end

Comment: @VivekMishra I already addressed the fact that I forgot to distinguish between posttypeid ==1 and posttypeid =2. That is fixed and so is the image, and query

Comment: it's still not working for me

Comment: I don't understand how you get that http://data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/476172/603177 . That url is only used internally by the QueryResult poller.

Comment: I can show you screenshot

Comment: yes, please do because no one seems to able to reproduce your problem. Are you logged in in SEDE? Or are you using the captcha to run the query?

Comment: I added screenshot and also that second id got appended when I click on `run query` button

Comment: But you do visit http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476172 first, right? And then click Run Query @VivekMishra

Comment: no from the query link that you posted

Comment: But the link in my post had always been http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476172 and that is the correct one.

Comment: It is still the same no effect `http://data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/476172/603179`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109819/discussion-between-rene-and-vivek-mishra).

Comment: now it's working but it takes much time to show the results
202.5 ms

Comment: And one more thing query returns 50000 records while title for that query is just top 50 users

Comment: @Vivek your connection is slow/broken, it's something on your side. Just happened to me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard when I posted this question , query was wrong, but now it has been corrected by rene

Comment: @Vivek still, you should never reach http://data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/476172/603179 unless something breaks, client side.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as problem is now solved therefore I can't do that now but it was problem then and discussed with rene regarding this issue

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me with this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389757/query-for-top-user-in-a-month-in-a-tag