# Query for Top User in a month in a tag

Tags: support, statistics, data-explorer

I am currently the top user in the Angular tag in the last 30 days.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/topusers

I do not know much about SEDE. I just want to create a query like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/52750/tag-rankings-fun) which I will be able to share in my profile.

Please help.

Comment: Link the top users page and make sure you're always at the top ;)

Comment: Sadly it's unlikely.. There are awesome developers, I think this is just once in a lifetime achievement and I want  to add it in profile. I have seen so many people do it, I don't know how to do it for myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1115290?tagname=angular&start=2019-08-24&end=2019-09-24) is close enough to replicate the results.

```
select top 30
       p.owneruserid as [User Link]
       , count(distinct p.id) [# Answers]
       , sum(case votetypeid 
             when 2 then 1 
             when 3 then -1
             end) [score]
       , sum(case votetypeid 
             when 2 then 10 
             when 3 then -2
             end) [ reputation]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.parentid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string?angular##
and v.votetypeid in (2,3)
and p.creationdate between ##start:string?2019-08-20## and ##end:string?2019-09-20##
and v.creationdate <= ##end:string?2019-09-20##
group by p.owneruserid
order by sum(case votetypeid 
             when 2 then 10 
             when 3 then -2
             end) desc
```

The query expects a tagname and a start and end date for the "30 days" to cover.

This is a result when run with a month worth of posts roughly from a month back:

[image: list of top answerers]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday so you need to pick your dates a bit careful.

Do give the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a try and say "Hi!" in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).